# Is onload equal to readyState==4 in XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am confuse about the xhr return event, as I can tell, there are not so much different between *onreadystatechange --> readyState == 4* and onload, is it true?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("Get", url, false);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4)
    {
        /* do some thing*/
    }
};

xhr.send(null);
```

or

```
xhr.onload = function() { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: If anyone is looking at this as an example note that it's using async=false (3rd argument of xhr.open) - which is not normally what you'd want.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It should be the same thing. `onload` was added in XMLHttpRequest 2 whereas `onreadystatechange` has been around since the original spec.

Comment: Seems, that mobile Safari does not come back when using onload. onreadystatechange works, though.

Comment: There is no real clear separation between XHR 1 and XHR 2 anymore, they have merged into one standard. The most common feature that represents XHR 2 is CORS support so from that standpoint XHR 2 didn't appear in IE until IE 10 but XHR.onload was supported in IE 9 which is typically believed to be XHR 1.

Answer (score 168):

This is *almost* always true. One significant difference, however, is that the `onreadystatechange` event handler also gets triggered with `readyState==4` in the cases where the `onerror` handler is usually triggered (typically a network connectivity issue). It gets a status of 0 in this case. I've verified this happens on the latest Chrome, Firefox and IE.

So if you are using `onerror` and are targeting modern browsers, you should not use `onreadystatechange` but should use `onload` instead, which seems to be guaranteed to only be called when the HTTP request has successfully completed (with a real response and status code). Otherwise you may end up getting two event handlers triggered in case of errors (which is how I empirically found out about this special case.)

Here is a link to a [Plunker test program](http://plnkr.co/edit/ycQbBr0vr7ceUP2p6PHy?p=preview) I wrote that lets you test different URLs and see the actual sequence of events and `readyState` values as seen by the JavaScript app in different cases. The JS code is also listed below:

```js
var xhr;
function test(url) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() { log(xhr, "readystatechange") });
    xhr.addEventListener("loadstart", function(ev) { log(xhr, "loadstart", ev.loaded + " of " + ev.total) });
    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(ev) { log(xhr, "progress", ev.loaded + " of " + ev.total) });
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", function() { log(xhr, "abort") });
    xhr.addEventListener("error", function() { log(xhr, "error") });
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function() { log(xhr, "load") });
    xhr.addEventListener("timeout", function(ev) { log(xhr, "timeout", ev.loaded + " of " + ev.total) });
    xhr.addEventListener("loadend", function(ev) { log(xhr, "loadend", ev.loaded + " of " + ev.total) });
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.send();
}

function clearLog() {
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = '';
}

function logText(msg) {
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += msg + "<br/>";
}

function log(xhr, evType, info) {
    var evInfo = evType;
    if (info)
        evInfo += " - " + info ;
    evInfo += " - readyState: " + xhr.readyState + ", status: " + xhr.status;
    logText(evInfo);
}

function selected(radio) {
    document.getElementById('url').value = radio.value;
}

function testUrl() {
    clearLog();
    var url = document.getElementById('url').value;
    if (!url)
        logText("Please select or type a URL");
    else {
        logText("++ Testing URL: " + url);
        test(url);
    }
}

function abort() {
    xhr.abort();
}
```

Comment: @Fernando To clarify, inside `onload`, `readyState === 4` is guaranteed to be true right?

Comment: @sam Yes, that seems to always be the case, though the opposite is clearly not true, as `readyState` can be 4 on `error` or `abort` cases too. This state basically means the load process has finished, whether successfully or not. For a normal, successful load, the final sequence of events is: `progress` (with all data loaded), `readystatechange` (with `readyState == 4`), `load`, `loadend`.

Comment: Keep in mind that `onload` also won't trigger if `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: That's true. That is one of the cases that triggers the `onerror` handler.

Comment: @FernandoEcheverria, I seriously doubt this answer is correct in its claim. Is there a test script?

Comment: @Pacerier : Yes, please see here:
[plnkr test](http://plnkr.co/edit/ycQbBr0vr7ceUP2p6PHy)

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but just for the sake of reference I will add this documentation of the XMLHttpRequest events: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#events where it points out that it's triggered only when "the fetch succeded"

Answer (score 16):

No, they are not the same. If you encounter a network error or abort the operation, `onload` will not be called. Actually, the closest event to `readyState === 4` would be `loadend`. 
The flow looks like this:

```
     onreadystatechange
      readyState === 4
             ⇓
 onload / onerror / onabort
             ⇓
         onloadend
```

Answer (score 2):

in simple code here how they are handle the error

```
xhr.onload = function() {
  // same or allowed cross origin
  if (this.status == 200) {

  }
  else {} // error http status not 200
};
xhr.onerror = function() {
  //error: cross origin, bad connection
};
```

VS

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (this.status == 200) {

    }
    else {} // error: cross origin, http status not 200, bad connection
  }
};
```