# Can one replace xhr.onreadystatechange with xhr.onload for AJAX calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I need to support major modern browsers only (IE10+, FF, Chrome, Safari)

Can I make this substitution as I want to simplify my code base:

**From:**

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            o.callback(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

**To:**

```
xhr.onload = function (test) {
    o.callback(xhr.responseText);
};
```

I don't feel that the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) is clear in this regard.

**Clarification:**

I choose not to use a framework.

Comment: As they are they are functionally equivalent since you do nothing if the request fails.

Comment: @elias94xx "Trying it out" is not feasible in this case. One would have to try it out on all versions of all major browsers, and there would still be no guaranteed support. Furthermore some browsers may not actually support the specifications they claim to support so looking it up may not be reasonable here either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is onload equal to readyState==4 in XMLHttpRequest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181090/is-onload-equal-to-readystate-4-in-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: clarification = +1 m8

Answer (score 19, accepted):

maybe you take a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181090/does-onload-equal-to-readystate-4-in-xmlhttprequest) and a look at [W3C: XMLHttpRequest](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html) it's the same if your browser supports xhr.onload. Requires XMLHttpRequest 2)

You can also write a wrapping function that emulates xhr.onload if it's not present.
(I think you need to override `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.onload = function(args){//calling onreadystatechanges somehow}`). If you only support modern browsers using xhr.onload should be available - the best solution is using a **framework** (like [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) or [mootools](/questions/tagged/mootools) that provides wrapping functionality for that.

Comment: xhr2 is suported by IE10+ and of course the other 3. http://caniuse.com/#search=xhr2

Comment: Update: it's 2017 - Frameworks are optional now that ES6 exists >_<

Comment: If the two are equivalent, then why does this MDN article nest the two: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Answer (score 16):

In the MDN documentation they state the following

> Events
>
> onreadystatechange as a property on the xhr object is supported in all
>   browsers.
>
> Since then, a number of additional event handlers were implemented in
>   various browsers (onload, onerror, onprogress, etc.). These are
>   supported in Firefox. In particular, see nsIXMLHttpRequestEventTarget
>   and Using XMLHttpRequest.
>
> More recent browsers, including Firefox, also support listening to the
>   XMLHttpRequest events via standard addEventListener APIs in addition
>   to setting on* properties to a handler function.

So I think you can assume that onreadystatechange is the way to go and onload is a addition that can be used if the browser supports it. @mr.VVoo answer is the correct one, to stick to w3c when in doubt.

Answer (score 4):

Since the original asker said "I need to support major modern browsers only (IE10+, FF, Chrome, Safari)" it is obvious that `onload`, `onerror`, etc are the ways to go. Also, as of today, `onreadystatechange` is pretty much obsolete, as you are obviously not going to support anything that old that it supports `onreadystatechange` only.

To sum it up, forget about `onreadystatechange`.

Comment: In 2017, this is pretty accurate. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19247992/1367414

Answer (score 1):

You can clean up your first example by doing this

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        o.callback(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Note, you probably want to check `onload` too with `this.status === 200` if you are doing something with the else statement. Although, if you are checking for errors, there is also `onerror`, which you can write something like

```
xhr.onerror = function(){
    console.log('Error: Do something else...');
}
```