# onload equivalent to onreadystatechange (readyState: 4, status: 200)

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

Is `onload` equivalent to `onreadystatechange` with `readyState` 4, `status` 200?

[This SO post says yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946291/can-one-replace-xhr-onreadystatechange-with-xhr-onload-for-ajax-calls)

But if they are equivalent, then why does [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) nest the two as such:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/bar/foo.txt", true);
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
      console.error(xhr.statusText);
    }
  }
};
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
  console.error(xhr.statusText);
};
xhr.send(null);
```

---

### [EDIT] Not duplicate of:

[Is onload equal to readyState==4 in XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181090/is-onload-equal-to-readystate-4-in-xmlhttprequest)

The second answer in the above post explains that it is not exactly the same as `readyState === 4`. However, if you include `status === 200` you have addressed the difference he/she talks about. My OP shows `status` nested inside `readyState`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is onload equal to readyState==4 in XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181090/is-onload-equal-to-readystate-4-in-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: @bigless Nope, not a duplicate. The second answer in the post you linked explains that it is not exactly the same as `readyState == 4`, but if you include `status == 200` you have addressed the difference he talks about. My OP shows `status` nested inside  `readyState`.

Comment: I believe that it is because he say that in case of onreadystatechange with readyState 4 can be onerror called too. onerror cannot happen together with onload so I think thats clear enough.

Comment: So to answer. status === 200 makes onload and onreadystatechange with readyState 4 equal.

Comment: @bigless But my question was: If they are equal, then why does MDN nest the two? I included all the info in my OP.

Comment: My two cents: on MDN, it should be onreadystatechange. Not onload.