# What does the onload method do in Json's xmlHttprequest object

Tags: json, xmlhttprequest, onload

I am taking a crash course on java script for this course https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs255/l-52473341/e-66738295/m-67610028, 
and I am really not sure what does an onload method of xmlHttprequest object does. I did google, but all the answers seems so advance and nothing relevant to the stuff I am learning. The course ended so no one will respond to my questions. Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

`onload` is not a method of the object, it's a *property*, like the `onclick` property of a DOM element. You assign a function to this property, and the function will be called when the corresponding event occurs (e.g. you click on an `A` element, and the `onclick` handler function you assigned is called). This function is called the *handler* of the event.

The `onload` handler of an `XMLHttpRequest` object is called when the server responds to the AJAX request and the response has been parsed by the browser. It's more common to use the `onreadystatechange` handler, though; this handler is called at various stages of processing of the AJAX request, and state `4` corresponds to the response being loaded. This is for historical reasons: `onreadystatechange` was in the original version of the API, `onload` was added later (see [Is onload equal to readyState==4 in XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181090/does-onload-equal-to-readystate-4-in-xmlhttprequest)).