# xmlhttprequest onload doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, onload

I'm trying to validate a form via javascript and xmlhttprequest and it doesn't work properly.
My onload function should pop up an alert, sometimes it does work and the alert pops up and sometimes not. I cant really see my mistake.

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  validateForm(document.myForm);
});


function validateForm(form) {

  if (form.FirstName.value.match(/^([A-Za-z ]+)$/) &&
    form.Surname.value.match(/^([A-Za-z ]+)$/) &&
    form.Verein.value.match(/^([A-Za-z ]+)$/) &&
    form.Headcoach.value.match(/^([A-Za-z ]+)$/) &&
    form.Assistantcoach.value.match(/^([A-Za-z ]+)$/) &&
    form.Rueckennummer.value.match(/^([0-9])$/) &&
    form.Rueckennummer.value > 3 &&
    form.Rueckennummer.value < 16 &&
    (document.getElementById("Aktiv1").checked || document.getElementById("Aktiv2").checked) &&
    (new Date(document.getElementById("idDate").value).getFullYear() <= new Date().getFullYear()) ) {

      senden(form);

  }else{
      alert("Einige Eingaben sind fehlerhaft. Bitte ueberpruefen Sie ihre 
            Eingaben.");
    }

}

function senden(form){
 var formData = new FormData(form);
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('POST', 'http://188.166.165.74:13337/api/players', true);
 xhr.responseType = 'json';
 xhr.onload = function() {
  alert("Daten wurden erfolgreich uebermittelt")
 };
 xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181090/is-onload-equal-to-readystate-4-in-xmlhttprequest - add an error handler too

Answer (score 2):

Try using `onreadystatechange` instead of `onload`...

```js
function senden(form){
 var formData = new FormData(form);
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('POST', 'http://188.166.165.74:13337/api/players', true);
 xhr.responseType = 'json';
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  alert("Daten wurden erfolgreich uebermittelt")
 };
 xhr.send(formData);
}
```