# Ajax request receives no response

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, es6-class

today I come for the following problem that I'm presenting with a new approach that I want to apply with the Ajax requests.

I have to explain that I commonly work with JQuery this type of requests, but I'm doing some tests with this new approach to see if I can solve some situations that I have not been able to solve with JQuery.

I'm working with a class that I'm developing and with which I'm just starting with the most basic, which is to make a request for plain text.

This is the basic ajax class that I have developed so far.

```
class Ajax {

  constructor () {

    this.xhr = null;
    if ( XMLHttpRequest ) {

      this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest ();

    } else if ( ActiveXObject ) {

      try {

        this.xhr = new ActiveXObject ( "MSXML2.XMLHTTP" );

      } catch ( e ) {

        try {

          this.xhr = new ActiveXObject ( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );

        } catch ( e ) {

          // throws error log
        }
      }
    }
    if ( !this.xhr ) {

      alert ( "The browser does not have support to make this type of requests to the server." );
    }
  }

  send ( method, event, url ) {

    var textoAjax = "";
    this.xhr.open ( method, url, true );
    this.xhr.setRequestHeader ( 'X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    this.xhr.setRequestHeader ( "Content-Type", "text/plain" );
    this.xhr.onreadystatechange = this.readyStateChange ();
    this.xhr.send ( event );
  }

  readyStateChange () {

    if ( ( this.xhr.readyState == 4 ) && ( this.xhr.status == "200" ) ) {

      document.getElementById ( "responsePhp" ).innerHTML = this.xhr.responseText;
    }
  }
}

function sendRequest () {

  let ajax = new Ajax ();
  ajax.send ( "POST", null, "sys/libs/common/PhpAjaxBridge.php" );
}
```

This is the test html.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Ajax Request</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/ecomod/indexes/Ajax.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="responsePhp"></div>
    <button onclick="sendRequest();">Send Simple Ajax Request</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the test php file.

```
header ( 'Content-type: text/plain' );
echo "Hi. What did you expect? ;P";
```

The problem is that when I click on the launcher button of my ajax request, although this arrives in my test php file, the answer to that request never arrives. I know that it is strange that there is no return on this request, given that it is a very simple example, but in fact that is the case.

I have tried to make some additional gadget as it is, to make use of the callback functions, but I still do not get an answer.

Here the implementation of the callback.

```
class Ajax {

  constructor () {

    this.xhr = null;
    if ( XMLHttpRequest ) {

      this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest ();

    } else if ( ActiveXObject ) {

      try {

        this.xhr = new ActiveXObject ( "MSXML2.XMLHTTP" );

      } catch ( e ) {

        try {

          this.xhr = new ActiveXObject ( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );

        } catch ( e ) {

          // throws error log
        }
      }
    }
    if ( !this.xhr ) {

      alert ( "The browser does not have support to make this type of requests to the server." );
    }
  }

  send ( method, event, url ) {

    var textoAjax = "";
    this.xhr.open ( method, url, true );
    this.xhr.setRequestHeader ( 'X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    this.xhr.setRequestHeader ( "Content-Type", "text/plain" );
    this.xhr.onreadystatechange = this.readyStateChange ( this.readyStateChangeCallback );
    this.xhr.send ( event );
  }

  readyStateChange ( callback ) {

    callback ( this.xhr.readyState );
  }

  readyStateChangeCallback ( state ) {

    if ( state == 4 ) {

      if ( this.xhr.status == 200 ) {

        document.getElementById ( "responsePhp" ).innerHTML = this.xhr.responseText;
      }
    }
  }
}

function sendRequest () {

  let ajax = new Ajax ();
  ajax.send ( "POST", null, "sys/libs/common/PhpAjaxBridge.php" );
}
```

As you can see here I show you the response from the server, but it never reaches the client

[image: Response Headers]

[image: Response Text]

What can be happening? What can I be forgetting or forgetting?

Thanks in advance.

PD: I have reviewed many threads in this forum and many others but none can explain what is happening or at least do not explain what happens to me, I have tried any solution that they have presented but none manages to unveil the mystery that it happens to me. :s
Sorry for the length but I wanted to be very explicit and place the code as is with the errors described

update: if I eliminate the parentheses in the line

```
this.xhr.onreadystatechange = this.readyStateChange ();
```

as suggested by Phil, the following error occurs

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of undefined at XMLHttpRequest.readyStateChange (Ajax.js:84)

where the line in question is this

```
if ( ( this.xhr.readyState == 4 ) && ( this.xhr.status == 200 ) ) {
```

On the other hand I must note that this.xhr.readyState only comes to take the value 1. The values 2, 3 and 4 never get to receive

Comment: `this.xhr.onreadystatechange = this.readyStateChange ();`  you're executing the `readyStateChange()` method here immediately instead of assigning it as a callback. Even if you remove the `()`, you're still going to run into problems accessing `this`.

Comment: The TL;DR of the duplicate posts is that you want `this.xhr.onreadystatechange = () => { this.readyStateChange() }`. You might also be interested in the [`onload` event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9181090/283366) as well as the more modern [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly, in the present problem, the same problem, but in the change another problem is presented and it is the next line. if ( ( this.xhr.readyState == 4 ) && ( this.xhr.status == 200 ) ) { with this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of undefined at XMLHttpRequest.readyStateChange"

Comment: As I mentioned in my PD: I have reviewed many threads in this forum and many others but none can explain what is happening or at least do not explain what happens to me

Comment: As always, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53254074/edit) to show any recent code changes. It also helps to list those other posts you've looked at and tried to use and explain, if possible, how they have not solved your problem.

Comment: In fact, the readyState of the XMLHttpRequest object only reaches values up to 1. The subsequent values 2, 3 and 4 do not receive them.

Comment: I mentioned in my first comment... _"Even if you remove the `()`, you're still going to run into problems accessing `this`"_ and provided a solution in my second comment. The duplicate posts should also make it clear what to do