# Difference between onreadystatechange and onload

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I tested two kinds of doing `XHR`:

1.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (this.readyState == 4 && xhr.status !== 500) {

                function getElementByXpath(path) {
```

2.

```
xhr.onload= function() {

                function getElementByXpath(path) {
```

and don't realized any difference. Could somebody point me to it? Or is there realy no one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is onload equal to readyState==4 in XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181090/is-onload-equal-to-readystate-4-in-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `readystatechange` event fires every time the [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) changes (which is several times).

A `load` event fires only when the request has completed successfully.

In your example you add some extra tests to your `readystatechange` handler to test if it has reached the final state (`4` (unless there are certain kinds of error in which case it will be `0`)) and to make sure it isn't a `500` error. There are other errors which would not trigger a `load` event.

Comment: Does it mean the result of `xhr.onLoad` is always data, while the result of `readystatechange` could be, data, undefined and 0?

Comment: No. You've confusing the `readyState` with the `responseText`.